# Sum of first $1+3+9+\cdots+3^n$ natural numbers.

Tags: induction

How to prove that the sum of the first $1+3+9+\cdots+3^n$ natural numbers is equal to $1^2+3^2+9^2+\cdots+(3^n)^2$?

I've tried induction, but I can't get through the induction step. The base is simple, but in the step I can only use the induction hypothesis in a way that would give me the conclusion that the sum of the first $1+3+9+\cdots+3^{n+1}$ is equal to the sum of the first $1+3+9+\cdots+3^n$ numbers, but also the sum of the remaining $3^{n+1}$ numbers, and I don't know how to proceed from here. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of an arithmetic sequence?

Comment: @hardmath I think it's a little deeper than that - it's the sum of positive integers *up to* the sum of the geometric progression. Of course, this does allow you to compose the formulae if you know them and skip induction entirely.

Comment: @platty Yes, I know the formula.

Comment: @hardmath I'm not sure I know what you're talking about so I don't think I'd be able to do it that way.

Comment: @implicati0n Hint: $\;m=1+3+3^2+\dots+3^n=(3^{n+1}-1)/2\,$, and the sum of the first $m$ natural numbers is $m(m+1)/2\,$. P.S. Don't know why you tagged the question `induction` because you don't need induction (unless you insist on using it for some reason).

Comment: In that case, you can also consider the set of the numbers from $\sum_{i=1}^n 3^i+1$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 3^i$ as an arithmetic sequence and apply the formula for the induction step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need induction; you can actually show equality with a relatively well-known (though perhaps at first "tricky") summation technique:

Well first, what is $1+3+9+\cdots+3^n$? Define that quantity to be $N$, and note that $3N = 3+9+\cdots+3^n+3^{n+1} = N + 3^{n+1}-1$, so $2N = 3^{n+1}-1$, and $N = \frac12(3^{n+1}-1)$.

Now that you know how high you are summing, you get:

$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^Ni = \frac12N(N+1) = \frac18(3^{n+1}-1)(3^{n+1}+1) = \frac18(9^{n+1}-1)
$$

Now, consider $S' = 1^2 + 3^2 + 9^2+\cdots + 3^{2n}$. Note that $9S' = 3^2 + 9^2 + \cdots + 3^{2n} + 3^{2n+2} = S' + 3^{2n+2} - 1$, so $8S' = 9^{n+1} - 1$, and $S' = \frac18(9^{n+1}-1)$.

Since $S' = S$, you are done.